Ansible wrong result when comparing variable to int
When comparing an stdout (which equals 17, verified with debug) and a int, the enter code here
 tasks:
    - name: Check Java version
      shell: "java -version 2>&1 | grep version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/\"//g' | cut -d \".\" -f1"
      register: java_version

    - name: set fact
      set_fact:
        java_v: "{{ java_version.stdout | int }}"

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: java version is 17
      when: java_v == 17


but results seems to be FALSE when comparing the stdout value to 17
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

i have tried also by setting a conversion; but still the comparaison result is FALSE
    - name: Convert stdout to integer
      set_fact:
        integer_output: "{{ java_version.stdout | int }}"

Anything i'm doing wrong please?
Thanks in advance

You do not need quotes around the entire shell command.  That is why you are being forced to escape the quotes.

You can't convert a string var into integer with | int in set_fact, since set_fact will be always a string

Some boolean values (yes, no, true, false) will always be converted to boolean type, unless DEFAULT_JINJA2_NATIVE is enabled. This is done so the var=value booleans, otherwise it would only be able to create strings, but it also prevents using those values to create YAML strings.

and which is the expected behavior. Also there is no need for the intermediate fact at all. Just only do
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: java version is 17
  when: java_version | int = 17

or
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: java version is 17
  when: java_version == '17'

Furthermore, it is recommended to use package_facts module – Package information as facts if possible. You might also be interested in type_debug filter – show input data type.
Somehow Similar Q&A

Whats the best way in Ansible to check if a command is available?
Ansible: How to install a package only if same version not installed?
Why is the Ansible task failing without giving any error?

